# MessageBodyWritter error in jersey REST call

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey

I'm bulding a REST application using Jersey but I'm getting quite frustrated because I can't understand why am I always getting this error:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class domain.transfer.ListOntologies, genericType=class domain.transfer.ListOntologies.
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

My resource implementation:

```
@GET @Path("/getOntologies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ListOntologies getAllOntologies() {

    // Just a list of OWL Ontologies
    List<OWLOntology> ontologies = repository.getOntologies();
    TransferOntologyOperation transferAllOntologiesOp = new TransferOntologyOperation(ontologies);

    // Transforms OWLOntologies to OntologyTransfer, which have the @XmlRootElement annotation
    ArrayList<OntologyTransfer> ontologiesToTransfer = transferAllOntologiesOp.fullyTransformOntologies();

    ListOntologies list = new ListOntologies();

    // The list object contains a list of OntologyTransfer objects
    list.setOntologies(ontologiesToTransfer);
    return list;
}
```

The `OntologyList` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ListOntologies {

    private List<OntologyTransfer> ontologies;

    public ListOntologies() {

    }

    public List<OntologyTransfer> getOntologies() {
        return ontologies;
    }

    public void setOntologies(List<OntologyTransfer> ontologies) {
        this.ontologies = ontologies;
    }
}
```

The `OntologyTransfer` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class OntologyTransfer {

    private String namespace;

    private List<String> classes;

    private List<String> instances;

    private List<String> objectProperties;

    private List<String> dataProperties;

    public OntologyTransfer() {

    }

    public OntologyTransfer(String namespace, ArrayList<String> classes, ArrayList<String> instances,
            ArrayList<String> objectProperties, ArrayList<String> dataProperties) {
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.classes = classes;
        this.instances = instances;
        this.objectProperties = objectProperties;
        this.dataProperties = dataProperties;
    }

    // getters and setters for all class attributes
}
```

Every time I test the method `getAllOntologies` I get the error I presented above.
I've tested also the code:

```
@GET @Path("/getOntologies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<OntologyTransfer> getAllOntologies() {
    List<OWLOntology> ontologies = repository.getOntologies();
    TransferOntologyOperation transferAllOntologiesOp = new TransferOntologyOperation(ontologies);
    ArrayList<OntologyTransfer> ontologiesToTransfer = transferAllOntologiesOp.fullyTransformOntologies();
    return ontologiesToTransfer;
}
```

But I get the error:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<domain.transfer.OntologyTransfer>`
```

I know that my `pom.xml` has all the current jars because I can, for example, change the `ListOntologies` class to:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ListOntologies {

    private List<String> ontologies;

    public ListOntologies() {

    }

    public List<String> getOntologies() {
        return ontologies;
    }

    public void setOntologies(List<String> ontologies) {
        this.ontologies = ontologies;
    }
}
```

And change the `getAllOntologies` method to:

```
@GET @Path("/getOntologies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ListOntologies getAllOntologies() {
    ListOntologies list = new ListOntologies();
    ArrayList<String> stringsTest = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringsTest.add("Testing");
    list.setOntologies(stringsTest);
    return list;
}
```

And this code works. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Why can't I return either an object which has a list of `OntologyTransfer` or simply return an ArrayList of `OntologyTransfer` directly in the `getAllOntologies` method?

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question, but do you get a similar error if you change all your media-types to application/xml? What library are you using for serialising to json?